# Is frida-server latest version compatible with old Android versions

Tags: dynamic-analysis, frida

I'm trying to figure out, if it's appropriate to use `frida-server` latest version (`12.8.x` at the moment of writing this question), on any Android version (even the old ones like KitKat).

I'm asking this question, because Android apps keep crashing, so I'm trying to figure out if the problem is Frida version.

Comment: Does any app crashes or just one or two specific apps?

Comment: @Robert I tried it on android 5 emulator, and all apps crashes without exception.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using the newest Frida to tinker around with a Galaxy S4 running Android 5.1 - works just fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

Very well functional, in my projects, when using for Android version 4.0